# Why the test charge is brought with infinitesimally slow speed?

Tags: electrostatics, velocity, potential, potential-energy

In my book it is written that:
While explaining the electrostatic potential energy,

> ...in bringing the test charge q from R to P,we apply an external force just enough to counter the repulsive force.This means there is no net force on or **acceleration of the charge q** when its is is brought from R to P i.e it is **brought with infinitesimally slow constant speed**

What is the requirement of this condition?How the results(amount of P.E) would have been different if this condition is not met?

Comment: If it is moved with speed, then the particle in it's final state would have not just potential energy but kinetic energy as well.

Comment: @Mew,And an accelerating charge produces electromagnetic radiation.Does emisssion of electromagnetic radiation have any effect on the potential energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In defining electric potential energy, we assume that it is the work done in bringing a test charge $Q$ from infinity to a point in some electric field, without accelerating it. Why we require no acceleration?

When the charge is accelerated, then it emits electromagnetic radiation. Radiated energy is lost from the system forever. Hence depending on the acceleration of the charge, we can only state the remaining energy stored in the field of the combined system of the two charges separated by a finite distance. But this is not a standard way of talking physics.

So, we put a constraint that the charge should be brought from infinity without accelerating it, or by maintaining at uniform speed, so that there is no energy radiation. Hence the entire energy, which is simply a function of the charges and the separation distance between them, is stored in the combined field due to the two charges. This seems to be a standard definition.

Otherwise as a matter of energy conservation, one need to consider the radiated energy also, which in turn depend on the acceleration of the charge. Also, the radiated energy is not a simple function. But the real problem is that this lost energy cannot be accounted as the potential energy stored in the system. It is because the potential energy stored in the system of the charges is simply the energy stored in the combined electric field of both.

Answer (score -1):

An accelerating charge radiates Electromagnetic waves that carry energy,
the static electric potential difference does not account for the radiative exchange.
To measure therefore the work done by the static potential difference while moving a charge from one place to another, must be performed so that the charge does not radiate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

The point is...THE LAW OF CONSERVATION OF ENERGY.

What do you mean by total energy?
It is the sum of Kinetic + potential Energies right..?

So, While Calculating the PURE POTENTIAL ENERGY, there is no need for Kinetic Energy to act. If moved fast, it causes kinetic energy. By this, we will be having some total energy, but not Pure Potential Energy. If you are talking about Potential energy than only that should get involved and not Kinetic Energy.

Hope This Helps!